# Difference between the following phrases

Tags: translation, word-choice

I was coming up with a phrase that means "don't look at me too much." in a very formal tone. I thought of many sentences but I don't know which one is the most correct one.

1) **あまり見ないでくれ**

2) **あまり見ないでくれませんか**

3) **あまり見ないでくれないか**

4) **あまり私を見るな**

5) **あまり見ないで**

I'd like to know the difference between each one of them.

(Also, the fourth sentence feels informal but I can't seem to find a formal wording for it)

Answer (score 1):

> I was coming up with a phrase that means "don't look at me too much."

"Look at me" could translate to a number of things, if you mean "watch what I'm doing" you might want to use the verb 観察【かんさつ】する rather than みる.

> in a very formal tone.
>
> 1) あまり見ないでくれ
>
> 2) あまり見ないでくれませんか
>
> 3) あまり見ないでくれないか
>
> 4) あまり私を見るな
>
> 5) あまり見ないで

None of these is remotely formal in tone! 2, 3, and 5 are more or less casual and 1 and 4 are pretty blunt. The above stuff in formal Japanese looks something like this:

私をご覧【らん】にならないようよろしくお願いします。

Comment: I see, but just to clarify, all of the sentences I came up with mean "Don't look at me too much." If we put aside formality and informality, right?

Comment: Yes, they all work as Japanese phrases.

Comment: 「私をご覧にならないようよろしくお願いします」って誰がどんな状況で言うねん・・

Comment: @Chocolate - 鶴？

Comment: あ～なるほろね........